How to breakdown param line of code like this? shortcut on vcode
Anyone here can tell me
I'd like to breakdown my code from this, shortcut or something
<img src="images/triceratops_4584837.png" height="60" alt="">

to this
<img 
  src="images/triceratops_4584837.png" 
  height="60" 
  alt=""
>

